# restart app when global static variables are killed android

Tags: android, variables, crash, global, restart

I have many global final constants in my application. I populate these constants from a json file during application startup. As recommended by many people, I am using the application class to keep the global variables in memory. But sometimes, after I close the application and play around with other apps and then come back to my app, it crashes. I understand this is because the system kills the process so these static variables are lost from memory. The recommended solution is to use sharedpreferences or other persistant storage methods to store these global variables. But I need a quick and easy solution to 'fix' this issue. For example, What is the easiest way to force restart the app, if the system kills the process(while the app in running in the background) and user comes back to the app later? I hope my question is clear.

Thanks in advance

Tom

Answer (score 1):

1. As Kai suggested, i.e.:

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends Application {

       @Override
       public void onCreate(){
           super.onCreate();
           initVariables();
       }   
   }
   ```
2. Or use accessors:

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends Application {

       MyVar var;
       public MyVar getVar(){
           if(var == null){
               initVariables();
           }
           return var;
       }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

Once your app is being paused (not visible to users), by **specification** Android system can simply kill the process your app resides in without any additional callback, so what you are trying to do is playing against system behavior.

If you keep those variables in your Application class, then you can simply reload those variables when your Application class is being loaded.